# Are lines numbers decorators on the roadmap?

Tags: support, feature-request, questions

Is Stack Overflow considering to add lines numbers decorators to the questions so we can all better faster address some spots in the OP's questions?

Comment: Would be lovely when someone edits the code and the line numbers don't match the comments anymore.

Answer (score 7):

That would not work across different versions of the site (desktop/mobile) and generally be a world of pain and suffering to implement well - for no obvious major benefit.

This is usually done by simply quoting from the OP's question and that has worked very well so far.